# Mapping profile instance doesn't creates

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflection, automapper

I'm trying to add automapping models with reflection, I created an interface `IMapFrom<>` and implemented it in all dtos.
Then I created class

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile(Assembly assembly)
        => ApplyMappingsFromAssembly(assembly);

    private void ApplyMappingsFromAssembly(Assembly assembly)
    {
        var types = assembly
            .GetExportedTypes()
            .Where(t => t
                .GetInterfaces()
                .Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMapFrom<>)))
            .ToList();

        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

            const string mappingMethodName = "Mapping";

            var methodInfo = type.GetMethod(mappingMethodName)
                             ?? type.GetInterface("IMapFrom`1")?.GetMethod(mappingMethodName);

            methodInfo?.Invoke(instance, new object[] { this });
        }
    }
}
```

And add it in service collection

```
public static IServiceCollection AddAutoMapperProfile(IServiceCollection services, Assembly assembly)
         => services
             .AddAutoMapper(
                 (_, config) => config
                     .AddProfile(new MappingProfile(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly())),
                 Array.Empty<Assembly>());
```

Why the class instance is not created? Because of this I can't convert the model into a dto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

Define IMapFrom:

```
public interface IMapFrom<T>
    {
        void Mapping(Profile profile) => profile.CreateMap(typeof(T), GetType());
    }
```

Then add Mapping profile:

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            ApplyMappingsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        }

        private void ApplyMappingsFromAssembly(Assembly assembly)
        {
            var types = assembly.GetExportedTypes()
                .Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any(i =>
                    i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMapFrom<>)))
                .ToList();

            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

                var methodInfo = type.GetMethod("Mapping")
                    ?? type.GetInterface("IMapFrom`1")?.GetMethod("Mapping");

                methodInfo?.Invoke(instance, new object[] { this });

            }
        }
    }
```

Create DI method:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddAutoMapperProfile(this IServiceCollection services)
        {

            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            services.AddAutoMapper(assembly);
            return services;
        }
```

and at the end call DI method that you created:

```
...
services.AddAutoMapperProfile();
...
```